# Distance between centroid and a point of an equilateral triangle with side length of x.

Tags: trigonometry

I want to create an equilateral triangle in 2D with a side length of x. If I can find the length between the centroid and one of the vertices, I should be able to rotate it to create the triangle.
So my question would be ... what is the distance between centroid and one of the vertices if the side of an equilateral triangle has to be kept x?
Is there is a faster way to calculate the 3 vertices of the triangle, with centroid at x1,y1 with side length of x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let centroid be O and your triangle be ABC

By cosine theorem,

$AB^2 = OA^2+OB^2-2\cdot OA\cdot OB\cdot\cos\theta$

$x^2 = 2OA^2\cdot\big(1-\cos(\frac{2\pi}3)\big) = 3OA^2$

$OA = \frac x{\sqrt3}$